# why the color is not same

Tags: materials

In the scene the material and the modifier same. But why the result not same. Test tube liquid has light color and bowl has dark color

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion why the color look different.

Comment: it looks like you have an HDRI but you didn't pack it into the file, please do it if you want us to test a render

Comment: @moonboots done

Comment: could you please be more precise? What are the modes where you see differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is quite simple: transmission depth

In the real world, if you look at a glass of water, it is transparent, while the sea is blu. 
That's because when your partially transparent material is thicker, more light is stopped and its color becomes darker.

You can see in your scene that the bowl is much larger than the tube, so it stops more light.

if you watch it from above you can see that the bowl is now lighter, because the light has less material to go through, and its color is similar to the tube

[image]

So, if your goal is photorealism, this scene is accurate.
If you want them to be the same color you can "water down" (make the color lighter or the transparency higher) the liquid in the bowl, but then it would become physically incorrect